# Return line of largest field in list of dictionaries text file with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, erpnext

I'm writing a Python script. I need to return line that contain largest 'uid' field from a text file.
For example, in the below text file example:

```
{
    "uid": 683,
    "user_id": "2",
    "timestamp": datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 17, 16, 39, 54),
    "status": 1,
    "punch": 0,
}, {
    "uid": 684,
    "user_id": "4",
    "timestamp": datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 17, 16, 41, 20),
    "status": 1,
    "punch": 0,
}
```

Return Text File ex:

```
{
    "uid": 684,
    "user_id": "4",
    "timestamp": datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 17, 16, 41, 20),
    "status": 1,
    "punch": 0,
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my solution, instead of reading a text file I used a text from string variable `text`.

Final result (entry with maximal uid) is contained inside `max_entry` variable. This result I write as string into text file `result.txt`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVDLCsJADLznK8JetsVF@rI@wC8RkdUGLLp1aVNRxG@vqVQPehEDgcyQCZPxV96fqrTrSudPNWNhmbh0BMB0YVyiUgpugFKqLQu1wHyWmgE3VG@enErUwPXahq3zwr5ujV9DkERJZHBiMJ5K5wbTucAsHMQi5LYRZTwQvq12e8GRgbvBDxvZt43sTxtZbDCJfrIBfSAgp6yEQ2d7DPRK4wifcY1Qr3UIzl42VHF9lRWZg37b4IF6fLRuW1ikBdJKyyt6HYKvy4qDtyrsugc)

```
import datetime

text = """
{
    "uid": 683,
    "user_id": "2",
    "timestamp": datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 17, 16, 39, 54),
    "status": 1,
    "punch": 0,
}, {
    "uid": 684,
    "user_id": "4",
    "timestamp": datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 17, 16, 41, 20),
    "status": 1,
    "punch": 0,
}
"""

data = eval('[' + text + ']')
max_entry = max(data, key = lambda e: e['uid'])
print(max_entry)

with open('result.txt', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    f.write(str(max_entry))
```

Output:

```
{'uid': 684, 'user_id': '4', 'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 17, 16, 41, 20), 'status': 1, 'punch': 0}
```

Comment: really interesting use of the eval() method, haven't seen this before

Comment: that's... a really elegant solution

Answer (score 1):

You show that your "text-file" is a list of dictionaries.
So you could do something like:

```
import datetime

text_file = {
    "uid": 683,
    "user_id": "2",
    "timestamp": datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 17, 16, 39, 54),
    "status": 1,
    "punch": 0,
}, {
    "uid": 684,
    "user_id": "4",
    "timestamp": datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 17, 16, 41, 20),
    "status": 1,
    "punch": 0,
}

def return_highest_ui_line(text_file):
    temp = []
    for i,sub_dict in enumerate(text_file):
        temp.append([sub_dict['uid'],i])
    return text_file[sorted(temp)[-1][1]]


return_highest_ui_line(text_file)

output:
{'uid': 684,
 'user_id': '4',
 'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 17, 16, 41, 20),
 'status': 1,
 'punch': 0}
```

Comment: I tried this but i got an error : TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: I assumed it's a dict, I didn't use eval()

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by:

```
import datetime
with open('C:/Users/UI UX/Desktop/newss.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        data = eval('[' + line + ']')
        max_entry = max(data, key=lambda e: e['uid'])
        print(max_entry)

        with open('result.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            f.write(str(max_entry))
```